# React Native error ':react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, android-ndk

I was using expo until yesterday for almost a year for developing alot of apps for my clients.
Recently, a client came with a request that cant be done with expo, and I need to use react native, so I decided to learn it.
I managed to install react-native and run the basic template on my android device.
But whenever i trying to install a package, no matter what package, there is an error that looks like this (this example is for the package react-native-image-picker):

> Execution failed for task ':react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-image-picker:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Shon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Shon.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e787b3ed0d2d661851eccf4c8f5cbaae\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Shon.gradle\caches\transforms-3\e787b3ed0d2d661851eccf4c8f5cbaae\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I verified that react-native is up to date,
and I tried to search for a solution in google and all of the suggestions weren't work.

Comment: Hey! Did you set up the development environment correctly? I suggest you check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native)